# How to appende Datetime to a DataFrame when exporting

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that needs to be exported, however I don't know how to append the Datetime properly. This has to be exported every month.

some of the arguments I used:

```
df_export = df.to_csv(path/export.txt, sep=';',index=False,line_terminator="\r\n")
```

The file should be something like this:

```
export_aaaa_mm.txt
```

Comment: What date do you want to append the file name with? The current date?

Answer (score 0):

Use f-strings

```
import datetime

df.to_csv(f"export_{datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y_%m')}.txt", sep=';',
      index=False,line_terminator="\r\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Python's `datetime` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to get the current year and month. Assuming `aaaa` in your example filename is supposed to be year, you can do the following:

```
from datetime import datetime

df.to_csv(f"path/export_{datetime.now().year}_{datetime.now().month}.txt", sep=';',index=False, line_terminator="\r\n")
```

F-strings only work on python3 and above. Example output from my terminal is here:

```
>>> print(f"path/export_{datetime.now().year}_{datetime.now().month}.txt")
path/export_2021_8.txt
```